# Stored procedure in pandas different database - Sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Running this code snippet works fine when typing the sql command directly into python.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver and login details go here)
sql = """ sql command that produces a table from the main database """
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
```

However, the dataframe returns a 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable', when I try to run the same code as a stored procedure.

`sql = " Use database2 exec  dbo.Open_Accounts "`

I am also aware that you can't use the go command in pyodbc

```
USE [database2]
GO
EXEC    [dbo].[Open_Accounts]
GO
```

and thus can't use the SQL code directly.

Comment: exec  database2.dbo.Open_Accounts?

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXEC Database2..Open_Accounts ?? --IF ANy Parameter There.

Comment: I this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Ok so Should I Delete The Ans